# Transition button when hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have this 2048x512 image with 4 stages of the transition but I can't figure out how to make it work.
[image: four icons of different contrast]

I know how to make it change to the last stage when hovering over it, but how do I add `transition` effect to it?

```
#instagram {
    width: 512px; height: 512px;
    background: url('/host/instagram.png') no-repeat left top;
}
#instagram:hover { background-position: -1542px 0px }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, also you added a jquery tag. Are you doing this in CSS or Jquery?

Comment: In your case, could you just do a transition for the background-color, because background-image is not a standard animatable property ( Chrome, Opera and Safari do support it though). Anyway http://rewish.github.io/jquery-bgswitcher/ is a jquery plugin which might be helpful for you.

Comment: What kind of a transition are you looking for? you could add `transition: background-position .2s`, but I'm not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: Do you see how that instagram button transitions at the button? That's what I'm trying to achieve:
http://petermosiman.com/reel

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need transition for this particular example, as all the frames are part of the same color pallete (white, gray, black). You can achieve similar (not identical, but not much different for a short-timer) effect using some font based icons (i.e.: font-awesome) with `transition` property and changing their color on `hover`: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr7h3d8g/)

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
...   
... 
<div class="icon-circle">
  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon-circle {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  border: 2rem solid black;
  transition: all .8s linear;
}
.icon-circle:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.fa-instagram {
  font-size: 20rem;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

However, if you do want to use image anyway, for sprite images you do it using CSS `animation` with `steps()` property: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25Lmtvnb/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="instagram"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#instagram {
  width: 512px; height: 512px;
  background: url('http://andreimartalog.com/host/instagram.png') no-repeat;
}
#instagram:hover { animation: enter 0.3s steps(3) forwards; }
@keyframes enter { 100% { background-position: -1536px } }
```